# How do I handle the "don't ask again" checkbox in Android Runtime Permission?

Tags: java, android, permissions, runtime-permissions

I want to handle this checkbox and take action accordingly.
The process I want to do is as follows; 
User triggers permission,

- Dont do anything if the user denied permission

User triggers permission again

- This time checkbox marks.
- Again, there is no action.

The user triggers permission again.

- This time the dialog show to go to the settings.

Most apps show the go to settings dialog after the second rejection. I dont want this.

Comment: persist a boolean somewhere. next time you open the app, check the value of the boolean

Comment: You can save a boolean to  SharedPreferences and check it every time the app starts

Comment: Possible duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41256582/how-to-handle-never-ask-again-checkbox-in-android-m. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353495/how-to-get-never-ask-again-option-in-runtime-permission

Answer (score 0):

if check box is checked store it using shared pref